# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 NetBeans Apache 12.2

Tags: java, netbeans

in my school they asked me to make an application with JavaFXML, but I am having many problems with the IDE that I use, which is NetBeans Apache 12.2, because I have JDK 15 installed and it seems that since JDK 1.8 JavaFx does not come by default Anyway, I had to download JDK 1.7.8 so that it would allow me to make an application with JavaFX to do step by step as much as possible what my teacher does (If it were up to me, I would use any Java application and import the libraries) , but at the time of compiling the program it seems that it is compiling with JDK 15 or 1.8, I don't know, but the point is that I get an error for having compiled with a larger JDK. And I do not know how to configure NetBeans so that that does not happen, I hope you can guide me.

```
ant -f "C:\\Users\\home\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\Laboratorio de Programación Orientada a Objetos\\JavaFXApplication2" jfxsa-run
jfxsa-run:
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/tools/ant/launch/Launcher : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Exception in thread "main" 
Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Answer (score 1):

Version 52.0 means Java 1.8 and the error message means that you are compiling your java code with a Java 1.8 compiler but you are running it with a Java version that is less than 1.8. I guess, from your question, that you are running with 1.7.

I suggest that you remove **all** your JDK installations and simply install JDK 1.8. You can download it from here...

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html

JDK 1.8 includes JavaFX.

If you prefer to use JDK 15, then you can download JavaFX 15 from here...

https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/

The following link explains the java class file versions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file